OncePerRequestFilter doesn't handle requests if it's initialized with @ConditionalOnProperty
I made an extending of OncePerRequestFilter:
public class ProjectVersionHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String HEADER_NAME = "Project-Version";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setHeader(HEADER_NAME, "2.0");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

And initialized a bean with @ConditionalOnProperty
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty("rpc.projectVersion")
    public ProjectVersionHeaderFilter projectVersionHeaderFilter() {

        log.info("Creating ProjectVersionHeaderFilter bean");
        return new ProjectVersionHeaderFilter();
    }

When I test it with @TestPropertySource like this:
    @Nested
    @TestPropertySource(properties = "rpc.projectVersion=\"2.0\"")
    public class ProjectVersionHeaderExistsTest {

        @SneakyThrows
        @DisplayName("В заголовок Project-Version ставится значение из пропертей")
        @Test
        void testProjectVersionHeaderExists() {

            String requestJson = "{" +
                    "\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"," +
                    "\"id\":\"12\"," +
                    "\"method\":\"method_with_customer_code\"," +
                    "\"params\":{\"customer_code\":\"123456789\"}" +
                    "}";
            log.info("request {} ", requestJson);

            mvc.perform(post(url).content(requestJson))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(header().string("Project-Version", "2.0"));
        }
    }

ProjectVersionHeaderFilter doesn't process test request
The bean is creating

but I can't realize why it's doesn't process request.
Have you any ideas? And thank you in advance!
I tried to remove @ConditionalOnProperty("rpc.projectVersion") and it works fine with it, but with this annotation it's not
